# The dimensions of the object in millimeters in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, visualization

It is necessary to display cubes on the plane, their dimensions are given in mm. and their coordinates in mm.
When I transmit this data to THREE, huge holes are obtained between the cubes, although they stand wall to wall, tell me how to convert the units correctly so that it looks like reality?

Link https://codepen.io/ybelyavsky/pen/rNJppMo

```
  const itemGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 100); // mm.
  const itemMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }); 
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(itemGeometry, itemMaterial);
  
  // mm. from 0.0.0
  mesh.position.x = 0;
  mesh.position.y = 100;
  mesh.position.z = 200;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0DHo.png)

Comment: Your question needs more details. Your code shows how you're generating *one* cube, but your image shows dozens of them. Please elaborate how you generate *all* cubes.

Comment: @Marquizzo Link https://codepen.io/ybelyavsky/pen/rNJppMo

Comment: Your codepen isn't working. All I see is a white canvas.